# Can't center ImageButton vertically

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a little problem, which I can't seem to fix. I created a ImageButton and a TextView. They are below each other, but I want them to center vertically and horizontally. I already got it horizontally, but whatever I do.... I can't get it centering vertically (So in the middle of the screen). Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0e2a56"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"  />
    <TextView
        android:text="Add project"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we use a **LinearLayout** layout:

- when `android:orientation="vertical"`, `android:layout_gravity` only works for **horizontal** orientation, but not for vertical orientation. **Left**, **right**, and **center_horizontal** were rendered.
- when `android:orientation="horizontal"`, `android:layout_gravity` only works for **vertical** orientation, but not for horizontal orientation. **top**, **bottom**, **center_vertical** were rendered.

so if you want to center the imagebutton and textview,you could wrap them in RelativeLayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#0e2a56"
  >
  <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     >
    <ImageButton
      android:src="@drawable/add"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"

      />
    <TextView
      android:text="Add project"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="35dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      />
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```